# two differents types values at the same column

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

I have this table which has a column in which I show a quantity. what I want is to show the quantity and the unit of measurement for example

```
60 meters
10 pieces
20 liters
(the first column)
```

this is the object that I show in table:

public class VentaDetalle {

```
private IntegerProperty idVentaDetalle;
private IntegerProperty idMercancia;
private StringProperty nombreMercancia;
private IntegerProperty idVentaGeneral;
private DoubleProperty cantidad;
private DoubleProperty general;
private DoubleProperty mayoreo;
private DoubleProperty subtotal;

public VentaDetalle(int idMercancia, String nombreMercancia, int idVentaGeneral,
        Double cantidad, double mayoreo, double general, Double subtotal) {
    this.idMercancia = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idMercancia);
    this.nombreMercancia = new SimpleStringProperty(nombreMercancia);
    this.idVentaGeneral = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idVentaGeneral);
    this.cantidad = new SimpleDoubleProperty(cantidad);
    this.mayoreo = new SimpleDoubleProperty(mayoreo);
    this.general = new SimpleDoubleProperty(general);
    this.subtotal = new SimpleDoubleProperty(subtotal);
}

//Metodos atributo: idVentaDetalle
public int getIdVentaDetalle() {
    return idVentaDetalle.get();
}

public void setIdVentaDetalle(int idVentaDetalle) {
    this.idVentaDetalle = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idVentaDetalle);
}

public IntegerProperty IdVentaDetalleProperty() {
    return idVentaDetalle;
}
//Metodos atributo: idMercancia

public int getIdMercancia() {
    return idMercancia.get();
}

public void setIdMercancia(int idMercancia) {
    this.idMercancia = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idMercancia);
}

public IntegerProperty IdMercanciaProperty() {
    return idMercancia;
}

//Metodos atributo: nombreMercancia
public String getNombreMercancia() {
    return nombreMercancia.get();
}

public void setNombreMercancia(String nombreMercancia) {
    this.nombreMercancia = new SimpleStringProperty(nombreMercancia);
}

public StringProperty NombreMercanciaProperty() {
    return nombreMercancia;
}

//Metodos atributo: idVentaGeneral
public int getIdVentaGeneral() {
    return idVentaGeneral.get();
}

public void setIdVentaGeneral(int idVentaGeneral) {
    this.idVentaGeneral = new SimpleIntegerProperty(idVentaGeneral);
}

public IntegerProperty IdVentaGeneralProperty() {
    return idVentaGeneral;
}
//Metodos atributo: cantidad

public Double getCantidad() {
    return cantidad.get();
}

public void setCantidad(Double cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = new SimpleDoubleProperty(cantidad);
}

public DoubleProperty CantidadProperty() {
    return cantidad;
}

//Metodos atributo: general
public Double getMayoreo() {
    return mayoreo.get();
}

public void setMayoreo(Double mayoreo) {
    this.mayoreo = new SimpleDoubleProperty(mayoreo);
}

public DoubleProperty MayoreoProperty() {
    return mayoreo;
}

//Metodos atributo: general
public Double getGeneral() {
    return general.get();
}

public void setGeneral(Double general) {
    this.general = new SimpleDoubleProperty(general);
}

public DoubleProperty GeneralProperty() {
    return general;
}
//Metodos atributo: subtotal

public Double getSubtotal() {
    return subtotal.get();
}

public void setSubtotal(Double subtotal) {
    this.subtotal = new SimpleDoubleProperty(subtotal);
}

public DoubleProperty SubtotalProperty() {
    return subtotal;
```

and I initialize the column like this:

```
clmnCantidad.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<VentaDetalle, Double>("cantidad"));
```

i take the unit from a databse with a table item
the table has name, stock, codebar and unit of measuremen

Comment: Provide some codes so that we know your data structure. How do you determine the unit?

Comment: i have edited my ask @Jai

Comment: I'm going to make a guess because there are a lot of non-english here. I'm going to assume "nombre" means name, and this name is used to match against another table in the database to find out which measurement unit the entry uses?

Comment: Yes i am using two tables of my database  item and saleDetail i want to do something like:

Comment: It may be neater to add the measurement unit property in `VentaDetalle` class, and when you are getting the list via SQL, you would do an inner-join SQL query to get the quantity and unit out at the same time. Then you could create a custom cell value factory that does a concatenation of these 2 properties.

Comment: Yes i am using two tables of my database  item and saleDetail i want to do something like: SELECT measurementUnit, sotck FROM item WHERE idItem = ? <br> and put the result of query in my column quantity (the first column of the picture) something like: 60 metters ("stock" + "quantity") @Jai

Comment: and how can i put two differents properties in the same column? if sotk is Double property and unit is String propety that is my doubt @Jai

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon you mean Double and String in a cell like: 60(double part) meter(string part) ? Or in one row double in another row string? Like 1st row: 60, 2nd row: meter?

Comment: You either need to have two different columns or you need to make one string column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer the part on the SQL query - ideally it should be some kind of `JOIN` statement that combines the two tables.

There are 2 main approaches when it comes to combine an `IntegerProperty` and a `StringProperty`.

#### Approach 1: Make a new property that concatenates them in the Model class

```
public class VentaDetalle {
    private DoubleProperty cantidad;
    private StringProperty measurementUnit;
    private StringProperty cantidadWithUnit;

    // Other properties

    // Public getters/setters

    public VentaDetalle(......) {
        // All the other stuff you did in constructor

        cantidadWithUnit.bind(Bindings.concat(cantidad, " ", measurementUnit));
    }
}
```

Then you just need to set the cell value factory:

```
clmnCantidad.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("cantidadWithUnit"));
```

#### Approach 2: Concatenate inside the cell value factory callback

```
clmnCantidad.setCellValueFactory(row ->
     Bindings.concat(row.getValue().cantidadProperty(), " ", row.getValue().measurementUnitProperty())
);
```